# How to build a dynamic url using get parameters in Flask

Tags: python, flask

i am using this code to get filter value from template by GET method:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def filters():
    if request.args.get('country') is None:
        results = Table.query.all()
        return render_template('index.html', results=results)

else:
    country = request.args.get('country')
    industry = request.args.get('industry')
    
    results = Table.query.filter(Table.country == country, Table.industry == industry).all()
    return render_template('index.html', results=results, country=country, industry=industry)
```

as a result, I get a url like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/?country=USA&industry=REIT
```

how can I get with GET or POST url requests of this kind:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/USA/REIT
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the feature you are looking for is called "Variable (Routing) Rules". From the [Flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#variable-rules):

> You can add variable sections to a URL by marking sections with `<variable_name>`. Your function then receives the `<variable_name>` as a keyword argument. Optionally, you can use a converter to specify the type of the argument like `<converter:variable_name>`.

```py
@app.route('/post/<int:post_id>')
def show_post(post_id):
    # show the post with the given id, the id is an integer
    return 'Post %d' % post_id
```

or in your case:

```py
@app.route('/<country>/<industry>')
def show_post(country, industry):
    results = Table.query.filter(Table.country == country, Table.industry == industry).all()
    return render_template('index.html', results=results, country=country, industry=industry)
```

Comment: When i use this i get: http://127.0.0.1:5000/USA/REIT/?country=USA&industry=REIT

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "I get". Where does that URL come from? I thought you wanted to know how the flask code would look _given_ a specific URL structure

Comment: In the template, I have a form with selections, the value of which is transmitted by a GET request. I select the country "USA" and the industry "REIT" in the select and get the URL http://127.0.0.1:5000/?country=USA&industry=REIT. I need everything to be the same, but only the URL is like http://127.0.0.1:5000/USA/REIT.